# next image with text in same time

Tags: android, textview, imageview, onclicklistener

I'm a beginner Android developer. I have list text when clicked next change text in one textview. I created imagelist how can when click next change imageview same time textview

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
int stringIdList[] = {R.string.one,R.string.two,R.string.three,R.string.four,R.string.five};
int imageIdList[] = {R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five};
int stringListCounter = 0;
int imageListCounter = 0;
TextView text21;
ImageView image2;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

            text21=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dyktext);
            image2=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagedyk);

    ImageButton next = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);
    ImageButton previous = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.previous);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if(id == R.id.next && stringListCounter  < stringIdList.length - 1 ) {
        stringListCounter++;

    }else if (id == R.id.previous && stringListCounter > 0 ) {
        stringListCounter--;

    }
    text21.setText(stringIdList[stringListCounter]);


}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if I understood you correctly...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    boolean updateText = false,
            updateImage = false;

    if(id == R.id.next) {
        if (stringListCounter  < stringIdList.length - 1 ) {
            stringListCounter++;
            updateText = true;
        }
        if (imageListCounter  < imageIdList.length - 1 ) {
            imageListCounter++;
            updateImage = true;
        }
    }else if (id == R.id.previous) {
        if (stringListCounter > 0 ) {
            stringListCounter--;
            updateText = true;
        }
        if (imageListCounter > 0 ) {
            imageListCounter--;
            updateImage = true;
        }
    }

    if (updateText) {
        text21.setText(stringIdList[stringListCounter]);
    }

    if (updateImage) {
        image2.setImageResource(imageIdList[imageListCounter]);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks @charlie success  . if you know better way for do this please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand your question correctly.
You would like to change the image in the ImageView at the same moment as you change yout text in the TextView, right?

In this case, you simply can add the command for setting a image resource below your setText() command.

In your case:

```
...
text21.setText(stringIdList[stringListCounter]);
image2.setImageResource(imageIdList[stringListCounter]);
```

Another hint: you should give your variables meaningful names (for example "textViewTitle" or "descriptionTV" ... instead of "text21")

I hope that I could help you!

Comment: I wouldn't use stringListCounter to index imageIdList. Sure it works now, but it will cause an exception if the two arrays differ in size at a later date.